# Sonicwall 2040 drops connection while uploading

Tags: sonicwall

I have **Sonicwall 2040 Pro**,
Firmware Version:  SonicOS Enhanced 4.2.1.9-20e   ROM Version:  SonicROM 2.1.0.0

I have nothing but default fw/nat rules/options set as I only made one server public visible

**WAN**: 
[NO] Enable 802.1p tagging
Interface MTU:  1500
[YES] Fragment non-VPN outbound packets larger than this Interface's MTU

**X0 LAN**:
[NO] Enable 802.1p tagging

I **did not** enable BWM on WAN interface therefore I do not have bandwidth management rules in effect at all.

Firewall
LAN >   WAN 1   192.168.2.200 (serverPC) Private    Any Any Allow   All
[this entry has DSCP and 802.1p Marking Settings action set to PRESERVE]

I noticed one thing that I not quite understand.

Let's say I have two machines, *1:a **desktopPC*** and *2:a **serverPC*** on the same X0 LAN subnet. 
**ServerPC** is visible in public (NAT/Fw rules).

Now:
if i'm downloading 1gb file from external server (http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html) both to **desktopPC** and to **serverPC** at once bandwidth is OK.

but

while i'm downloading 1gb file from external server (http://www.thinkbroadband.com/download.html) to **desktopPC** and on some point my **serverPC** starts to sending it's own 1gb file to the world on port:80, my desktopPC active download connection drops nearly to 0b/s and disconnects.

Am I missing someting?

---------------addon:
Downstream:10Mbps Upstream:5Mbps

[NO] Enable Gateway Anti-Virus

[NO] Enable Anti-Spyware

[YES] IPS Enabled

only High Priority Attacks  Prevent [YES] Detect [YES]

Comment: what kind of uplink connectivity do you have? If it's something like ADSL with a very low upload bandwith, it might be the start of an explanation. Also do you have IDS and/or Antivirus and/or any ip service inspection activated on the sonicwall?

Comment: Downstream:10Mbps Upstream:5Mbps
[NO] Enable Gateway Anti-Virus
[NO] Enable Anti-Spyware
[YES] IPS Enabled
only High Priority Attacks Prevent [YES] Detect [YES]

Comment: try disabling completely ip services

Comment: OMG! How weird. Thats it!! If i disable IPS on Sonicewall - there is NO PROBLEM with connections! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling IPS can solve this kind of problems on sonicwalls